# How to implement Rodney Brooks' subsumption model on ROS?

Tags: control, ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As we all know, Rodney Brooks' subsumption model is an extremely successful control architecture for robot. ROS provides us with a lot of driver and function packages. To construct a complex and intelligent robot software system, we should organize these packages. Subsumption model is a good choice. So, I want to know that whether ROS provide us with a mothod to implement subsumption model upon it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217877/how-to-implement-rodney-brooks%27-subsumption-model-on-ros?/) by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-09-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on 2015-09-19**:
I think the key idea of subsumption model is that the upper layer can either contain or suppress partial function units of lower layer. But the multiplexer is just a priority-based selector for velocity output. What's more，the multiplexer is just one single process.

**Comment by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on 2015-09-19**:
However, all the inhibitors and suppressors in subsumption model is decentralized causing that we can insert them in any place of any layers.

**Comment by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on 2015-09-19**:
the inhibitors are also very important, we can inhibit some behavior  of lower layer immediately, and then do some sensing or calculating things, output the result instead to the lower layer. but there is not inhibitor in the cmd velocity multiplexer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-19**:\

> But the multiplexer is just a priority-based selector for velocity output.

That is `cmd_vel_mux`: [topic_tools/mux](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux) can multiplex whatever you want.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-19**:\

> What's more，the multiplexer is just one single process.

Couldn't you start multiple of them? I can imagine `N` mux nodes, with coordination nodes calling the `mux/selected` service at appropriate times would come close to what you describe.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-19**:\

> but there is not inhibitor in the cmd velocity multiplexer.

How about switching to a 'zero input' in a `cmd_vel_mux` with (at least) two inputs: the normal one, and a topic that publishes a `Twist` with all zeros?

**Comment by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on 2015-09-19**:\

1. I don't think that "zero input" in a cmd_vel_mux is a good idea. I can not call it a inhibitor. If an output of a moudle in subsumption model is inhibited, the module send nothing at all. But the "zero" Twist msg is also a msg, it may call callback and activate some events of the lower layer.

**Comment by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on 2015-09-19**:
2. And another key word is "partial". The upper layer can either contain or suppress "partial" function units of lower layer. However, cmd_vel_mux just make the upper layer contain or suppress the function of the "whole" lower layer. Would I know your idea? Thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-20**:\

> But the "zero" Twist msg is also a msg, it may call callback and activate some events of the lower layer.

Not if you control all subs, and don't allow arbitrary connections between nodes. 'lower layers' should not be allowed to subscribe to upper layers directly, only through (after) the mux.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-20**:\

> The upper layer can either contain or suppress "partial" function units of lower layer.

ROS doesn't have an explicit 'layer' (or partition) concept, so you'll have to 'fiddle' with pub-sub relations to mimic it. I'd say 'inhibiting' a subset of nodes in a virtual 'layer' should be possible.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-20**:
If you'd like to 'merge' msgs on topics according to a weight (ie: `(topic_A * α) + (topic_B * (1 - α))`), you'll probably have to write some custom node(s). There probably are existing solutions for that, but I don't know about them.

**Comment by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on 2015-09-20**:
Thank you for your clear and patient answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Potential duplicate of [ros process in subsumption architecture](http://answers.ros.org/question/172499/ros-process-in-subsumption-architecture/).

The answer there by @dornhege is probably a good approach.

Can you clarify what you are looking for exactly? And why @dornhege's answer isn 't enough?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1